# Error with GraphQL.Types.EnumerationGraphType

Tags: c#, graphql, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to create class with enum and I have an error.

```
public class MarsWheather {
    public Season MarsSeason { get; set; }
}

public enum Season {
    winter,
    spring,
    summer,
    autumn
}
```

My graphql classes look like:

```
public class SolSchema : Schema
{
    public SolSchema(IServiceProvider sp) : base(sp)
    {
        Query = sp.GetRequiredService<SolDataQuery>();
        Mutation = sp.GetRequiredService<SolDataMutation>();
    }
}
public class SolDataQuery : ObjectGraphType<object>
{
    public SolDataQuery(INasaProvider nasaProvider)
    {
            Field<MarsWheatherType>("wheather", resolve: context => nasaProvider.GetAsync());
    }
}
public class MarsWheatherType : ObjectGraphType<MarsWheather>
{
    public MarsWheatherType()
    {
        Field(w => w.MarsSeason);
    }
}

public class SeasonEnum : EnumerationGraphType<Season>
{ }
```

I've registered it in startup.cs (ConfigureServices method) :

```
services.AddSingleton<SolDataQuery>();
        services.AddSingleton<SolDataMutation>();
        services.AddSingleton<SeasonEnum>();
        services.AddSingleton<MarsWheatherType>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISchema, SolSchema>();
```

I'm useing GraphQLPlayground. My request is :

> ```
> wheather {     
>  marsSeason}
> ```

After all of it I have an error:

> GraphQL.Execution.UnhandledError: Error executing document.\r\n ---> >System.InvalidOperationException: Required service for type >GraphQL.Types.EnumerationGraphType`1[Mars.Season] not found\r\n   at >GraphQL.Utilities.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type >serviceType) in /_/src/GraphQL/Utilities/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs:line 42

This error has code "INVALID_OPERATION"

Could somebody help me please? What do I do wrong?
P.S. If it help, I pushed this not finished project on [github](https://github.com/galenam/MarsWheather)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The correct code for MarsWheatherType is:

```
public class MarsWheatherType : ObjectGraphType<MarsWheather>
{
    public MarsWheatherType()
    {
        Field<SeasonEnum>("season", resolve: w => w.Source.MarsSeason);
    }
}
```